# Antiderivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+k^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus

I truly apologize if this is incredibly elementary -- I just want to be sure I'm evaluating this antiderivative correctly and I'm get disagreeing answers from SymboLab, Wolfram, and IntegralCalculator.

$$ \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+k^2}}dx $$
Let:
$$ (x-a) = k\tan\theta $$
$$ \implies x = k\tan\theta + a \ \ \ ; \ \ \theta = \tan^{-1}\big(\frac{x-a}{k}\big) $$
$$ \implies dx = k\sec^2\theta \ d\theta $$
$$ \therefore  \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+k^2}}dx = \int\frac{k\sec^2\theta}{\sqrt{k^2\tan^2\theta+k^2}} d\theta $$
$$ = \int\frac{k\sec^2\theta}{\sqrt{k^2(\tan^2\theta+1)}} d\theta $$
$$ = \int\frac{k\sec^2\theta}{\sqrt{k^2\sec^2\theta}} d\theta $$
$$ = \int\frac{k\sec^2\theta}{k\sec\theta} d\theta $$
$$ = \int \sec\theta \ d\theta $$
$$ = \ln | \sec\theta + \tan\theta | + C $$
$$ = \ln \Big| \sec\Big(\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{x-a}{k}\big)\Big)+ \tan\Big(\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{x-a}{k}\big)\Big) \Big| +C$$
$$ = \ln \Big| \frac{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+k^2}}{k}+ \frac{x-a}{k} \Big| +C$$
$$ = \ln \Big| \frac{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+k^2} + x-a}{k} \Big| +C$$
$$ = \ln \Big| \sqrt{(x-a)^2+k^2} + x-a \Big| \ - \  ln|k| +C$$

Did I miss anything? Not one of the online solvers I tried reached this solution... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just differentiate the obtained result and check if it matches exactly with the integrand!

Comment: Your answer is correct. I just copy pasted your final expression to find its derivative using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdx++%5Cln+%5CBig%7C+%5Csqrt%7B%28x-a%29%5E2%2Bk%5E2%7D+%2B+x-a+%5CBig%7C+%5C+-+%5C++ln%7Ck%7C+).

Comment: Thanks  I'm pretty embarrassed at not having thought of that... Won't happen again!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**
Yes the solution is correct, as shown by taking the derivative of the final expression.

(Whoops, didn't think of that!)